# Performant neighbour navigation

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I've been using neo4j for a little while now, and come across an issue with performance.

I've got a situation where I'm (essentially) modelling a cellular automata in a graph database. It isn't as simple as GoL and requires a lot of data which is why I opted for a graph database. But similar to a cellular automata nodes are connected to their neighbours and calculate their state based on the state of their neighbours.

As such I want a system like this:

```
TriggerNode --> CalculatesValue --> TriggersEventToNeighbours
ListeningNeighbour --> CalculatesValue --> TriggersEventToTheirNeighbours
ListeningNeighbour --> CalculatesValue --> TriggersEventToTheirNeighbours
ListeningNeighbour --> CalculatesValue --> TriggersEventToTheirNeighbours
...
```

In Neo4j however, using the various drivers, I can see that there will be huge amount of communication overhead between my programming environment and the database via the socket protocol.

I'm looking to eliminate this overhead.

Is there a Neo4j driver which has no performance overhead while going from `node-->relationship-->node`? If not, is there another graph database out there which can be used in this fashion?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/background-operations/` or `https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/database-introspection/`. You might have to write your own user defined functions in java, using the Neo4j java driver? That should speed things up considerably.  `https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/`

Comment: Yes if anything, the java-driver looks to be the way forward with Neo4j at least. I'm a little skeptical that will do it either though in my use case... But is worth a shot.

Comment: Please post your results so we all benefit from your experience! We're all learning together.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your connected "cluster" of nodes making up automata, you might want to consider InfiniteGraph.

The InfiniteGraph kernel in the client library caches the database data pages that are currently being used by the application. This can include millions of nodes and edges that get cached client-side. The cache uses a least-recently-used policy to flush database pages, writing pages that have been updated. Upon transaction commit, the remaining updated pages get written and the database reflects all changes.

Essentially, InfiniteGraph becomes an in-memory graph database tuned to each user's usage patterns with a massively scalable and fully distributed disk backing store.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information, I'll take a look into it 